# Fontawesome как кастомизировать библиотеку?

Tags: svg, шрифты, fontawesome

Добрый день уважаемые. При вёрстке сайта использовались иконочные шрифты из библиотеки [Fontawesome](http://fontawesome.io/icons/), но теперь есть необходимость минимизации размеров подгружаемых на сайт файлов. (110kB CSS + Fonts) Есть ли простой способ создать свой минимизированый шрифт избавившись от всего лишнего?Если чистка CSS мне ещё понятна, то вот как оптимизировать шрифты, нет ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть такой сайт: http://fontello.com/

В нем есть популярные библиотеки иконочных шрифтов, Fontawesome, например, присутствует.

Что можно сделать - на сайте вы выбираете какое конкретно иконки вам нужны, (поштучно) Если чего-то не хватает, можно загрузить в формате SVG-шрифта.

Как выбрали нужный набор символов - жмете Download Webfont - и получаете необходимый набор файлов, включая CSS, включающий только те конкретные иконки, которые вы выбрали, которые легко установить на сайт, и просто пользоваться.

При желании можно настроить имена иконок, чтобы не изменять CSS-классы в HTML